# Finding max date for a subset of records

Tags: excel, max, vlookup

Unfortunately I have to do this in Excel.

I need to find the most recent date for each ID code, within a range of two dates.  I can do each bit separately, but I cannot seem to put them together to get what I need.

For the following example data:

```
a   21/11/2012
b   17/12/2014
a   08/01/2013
b   03/12/2012
c   04/12/2012
c   05/12/2012
c   06/12/2013
```

If I am looking for the latest response between the 2012-13 academic year - 31/08/2012 to 1/9/2013  I would like to get the following result:

```
a   08/01/2013
b   03/12/2012
c   05/12/2012
```

I used the following array formula to get the latest date regardless of year:

```
{=MAX(IF($A$1:$A$7="a",$B$1:$B$7))}
```

And I used the following formula to get a date for within the academic year:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($B$1:$B$7,">="&$F$10,$B$1:$B$7,"<="&$G$10,$A$1:$A$7,"="&"a")>0,B1:B7,"")
```

(where F10 is 31/8/12 and G10 is 1/9/13)

I tried this... it didn't work:

```
{=IF(COUNTIFS($B$1:$B$7,">="&$F$10,$B$1:$B$7,"="&$G$10,$A$1:$A$7,"="&$E1)>0,MAX(IF($A$1:$A$7=E1,$B$1:$B$7)),"")}
```

I can't simply sort the column by decreasing date so the date it comes across first is the latest, because I also need to a similar thing for another column, and they aren't always in the same order.

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you were close with this:

```
{=MAX(IF($A$1:$A$7="a",$B$1:$B$7))}
```

You need to filter out the dates that don't match your criteria, which can be done with this:

```
IF($B$1:$B$7<=date(2013,9,1), ...
IF($B$1:$B$7>=date(2012,8,31), ...
```

You can't join them using `AND`, as it will convert the array to a single value

```
{=MAX(IF(AND($A$1:$A$7="a",
             $B$1:$B$7<=date(2013,9,1),
             $B$1:$B$7>=date(2012,8,31)
             ),$B$1:$B$7))}
```

will return either the 1st item in the **B1:B7** range, or 0, depending on how all the tests went.  So the next step is to daisy chain the `IF`'s together, which gives you this:

```
{=MAX(IF($A$1:$A$7="a",
          IF($B$1:$B$7<=$G$10,
              IF(B1:B7>=$F$10,$B$1:$B$7))))}
```

(spread out so you can see the nesting of the IF statements) Which will now give you the result you want: 8/1/2013

Comment: Added complication:  What if the ID value isn't in the source data?  e.g. what if the table included a letter d, but there was nothing to max for that?  I tried this amendment, but it just returns #VALUE:  `{=MAX(IF(F4="Y",IF($A$1:$A$7=E4,IF($B$1:$B$7<=$H$10,IF($B$1:$B$7>=$G$10,$B$1:$B$7))),""))}` (There is already a column with "Y" in saying if there is any data)

Comment: Ooh I just put the if in the wrong place ignore me :)  this works: `{=IF(F4="Y",MAX(IF($A$1:$A$7=E4,IF($B$1:$B$7<=$H$10,IF($B$1:$B$7>=$G$10,$B$1:$B$7)))),"")}`